# css-loader localIdentName: is a hash necessary for uniqueness?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

The [css-loader README](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/README.md#modules) suggests that `localIdentName` be set to

```
'[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
```

Is the hashing suffix necessary? Would it still be unique as this?

```
'[path][name]__[local]'
```

Why or why not?

The fact that #3 is an option in this [GitHub Issue discussion](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/194#issuecomment-262625515) leads me to believe it may not be necessary.

Comment: According to [this css-loader github comment](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/413#issue-203652063), the hash, by default, will be "a digest of the relative path and the local classname", which makes it seem completely redundant in your first example!

Answer (score 13):

The `localIdentName` is used along with the `modules` options:

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
  }
}
```

It generates longer class names like:

```
.src-styles-main__world-grid--R7u-K
 ---------------  ----------  -----
      path,name     local      hash

.src-styles-main__world-grid
 ---------------  ----------
      path,name     local
```

So, the hash would not be needed as long as path, name and class name generate unique IDs. It is very unlikely that the hash would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

[localidentname on webpack 4.35.3](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localidentname)

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is the hashing suffix necessary?**

Yes

**Would it still be unique as this?**

Would be yes and would be no. depends

**Why or why not?**

Then let see on [documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/README.md#modules)

> The query parameter modules enables the CSS Modules spec.
>   This enables local scoped CSS by default. (You can switch it off with
>   :global(...) or :global for selectors and/or rules.).
>
> By default CSS exports all classnames into a global selector scope.
>   Styles can be locally scoped to avoid globally scoping styles.

The main purpose is here:

> **Styles can be locally scoped to avoid globally scoping styles.**

You can do with this pattern `'[path][name]__[local]'`, but you break the main purpose for **scope**.

If you have project frontend framework like `angular` or `reactjs`. for example `angular` with `directive`/`component` or `reactjs` with `component`, this is the main purpose use scope css. With CSS modules, you can write normal CSS code and make sure, that it only applies to a given component. And we don't need overthinking name or long name for specific class name to avoid overwrite css